# how to programmatically query google scholar?

Tags: c#, .net, google-scholar

I want to develop a function that takes a keyword as input, queries Google Scholar using that keyword, and downloads the journals containing that keyword.

For the moment, I would like to avoid the classic way of using a `WebRequest` object.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like Google has provided an API for querying scholar.

I'm using c# .

Comment: You are correct on no API support. Head here to add your own support to getting an API for Google Scholar. http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=109

Comment: it goes beyond not having an API, as I mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523961/google-scholar-with-matlab/7587994#7587994) it is actually against the term-of-service. So be very careful, especially when automatically downloading.